# Error 404 - Java Servlet Doget Controller Method

Tags: java, servlets, controller

I cant run a simple hello world message on Servlet. Does anyone know what I am doing wrong? Below is my code:
[image: Controller]

[image: Error page]

The server is working normally. Tomcat is version 8.

Any help?

Comment: Please take the tour and read the help center.

Comment: Welxome. Please paste your code and output into the question, do not use images for this.

Comment: are you sure it should be `/fabricaweb/hello`? Where did that `fabricaweb`  come from? Servlet config / server config? This is not visible in your pictures, we can not know.

Comment: Zapl: "fabricaweb" is the name of the project. If I put out the "/hello", will show a simple hello world page, which comes from the index.html standard file. But, in this case, I want to display a simple message through the controller.

Answer (score -1):

Do you also have deployment descriptor file in your project?

Build new Dynamic Web Project in your IDE and Try this code:

```
@WebServlet(name = "Hello", urlPatterns = { "/hello" })
public class Hello extends HttpServlet {
protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request,
        HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
    PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
    out.print("Hello World");
}}
```

In this case you don't need to write .xml file for this.